# How to securely deploy PPK file in WPF C# app?

Tags: c#, sftp, private-key, winscp, winscp-net

I have a C# app that connects to a SFTP server to transfer log files.
The app achieves this by using WinSCP .NET assembly to connect to the server.

How do I securely store the `.ppk` private key file such that the user is not able to take this file to access the SFTP for themselves?

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#csharp

Based on the way the library reference the `.ppk`, it may not be possible to avoid storing the `.ppk` file on the local disk during run-time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the classic "DRM Problem", if a key exists on hardware the user has unrestricted physical access to it is impossible to make it so the user can't get the key. The only thing you can do is make it hard enough to get the key the effort to get it costs more than the reward of finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's generally no way to hide any kind of credentials that (any) application possess from the end user. You can only make them hard to be found, but it's questionable whether it is even worth the effort.

What you can (and should do) is to make sure the credentials grants only as little access as necessary.

So in your case, make sure the account, you authenticate with the private key:

- has only write access (no read access, nor even list)
- and has a low disk quota
- is regularly (or automatically) monitored for any unusual activity

---

Specifically regarding the private key for WinSCP .NET assembly:

Yes, it has to be stored on the disk (i.e. temporarily extracted to a temp folder). Though you can have the private key encrypted with a passphrase. And have the passphrase hard-coded in the application (obfuscated if your want).

See [`SessionOptions.SshPrivateKeyPassphrase`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions).

---

See also WinSCP article on [Protecting credentials used for automation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_protecting_credentials_for_automation).

Answer (score 0):

Since the WinSCP .NET assembly is calling the command-line scripting interface there is probably no way to do this.  I'm one of the developers of [edtFTPnet/PRO](https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/), which is a native .NET implementation of various file-transfer protocols, including SFTP.  Our interface allows you to set the private key using a byte-array (see [SecureFTPConnection.ClientPrivateKeyBytes](https://enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/doc/manual/api/html/P_EnterpriseDT_Net_Ftp_SecureFTPConnection_ClientPrivateKeyBytes.htm)).  Our product is not free, but it should get you where you want to go.